# Weird outcome of querying with SQLalchemy

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to search in my table of Venues to fund a matching name, the weird thing is that the outcome of my query is the translation to SQL!!! I don't know why this is happning and if anyone knows please teach me why?

this is my code:

the response variable is a dummy.

```
term_to_search_by = request.form.get('search_term')
  list_of_matches = Venue.query.filter(Venue.name.ilike(f'%{term_to_search_by}%'))
  print(list_of_matches)
  response={
    "count": 1,
    "data": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "The Dueling Pianos Bar",
      "num_upcoming_shows": 0,
    }]
  }
  return render_template('pages/search_venues.html', results=response, search_term=request.form.get('search_term', ''))
```

and this is what it prints:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2020 17:59:46] "POST /venues/search HTTP/1.1" 200 -
SELECT venue.id AS venue_id, venue.name AS venue_name, venue.genres AS venue_genres, venue.website AS venue_website, venue.seeking_talent AS venue_seeking_talent, venue.seeking_description AS venue_seeking_description, venue.city AS venue_city, venue.state AS venue_state, venue.address AS venue_address, venue.phone AS venue_phone, venue.image_link AS venue_image_link, venue.facebook_link AS venue_facebook_link 
FROM venue 
WHERE venue.name ILIKE %(name_1)s
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try ` print(list_of_matches.all())` - you need to execute the query by calling `.all()` or similar otherwise it's just a query, so printing it prints out the SQL.

Comment: you are absolutely true!!!! I don't know how did I miss it. Thank you

Comment: @afbigdad write a proper answer `^^`, was going to write one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by mistake, I didn't write the .all() at the end of the query so sqlalchamy printed the query itself, which is a neet feature!!!